# Does the auto-generated document id in Firebase/Firestore ever repeats?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Does the auto-generated document id ever repeats in the same firestore/firebase database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The auto-generated IDs for both Cloud Firestore and the Firebase Realtime Database are statistically guaranteed to be unique. You will not get the same ID when you call them repeatedly.

For a good explanation of how the push IDs from the Firebase Realtime Database are generated, have a look at this blog post: [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).